# Moving a list in a .csv file in R; cannot use `unlist` properly

Tags: r, list, csv

I produced in R the  list L, with

```
L <- list()
L[[1]] <-cbind ("Orks", "Eldar")      
L[[2]] <-cbind ("Nid", "Tau")
```

and output

```
> L
[[1]]
     [,1]  [,2]   
[1,] "Orks" "Eldar"

[[2]]
     [,1]  [,2] 
[1,] "Nid" "Tau"
```

I would like to write a .csv file with the following output

```
Number  Type
1       Orks, Eldar
2       Nid, Tau
```

i.e. transferring the list component L[[i]] to the i-th row of the file, with the above splitting and column names. I began to process the list by using

```
LL <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(L), nrow=2) )
```

but the output does not convince me, as I do not know how to bind the entries on the same row of the columns of `LL`, before sending them to the .csv file.

Is there a brute-force way to arrive at the .csv structure above, instead of playing around with `unlist` and its results?

I thank you very much!

Comment: `ldply`, under the right conditions, can do this quick and dirty too from the `plyr` package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to protect the `list` structure by using `I()` (which is more commonly used in `formula` objects)...

```
data.frame( Number = 1:length(L) , Type = I(L) )
#  Number        Type
#1      1 Orks, Eldar
#2      2    Nid, Tau
```

`I()` is a function which is used to...

> *Change the class of an object to indicate that it should be treated ‘as is’*

Comment: Interesting:  the output `df[1,2]` is a 1x2 matrix.  Any idea why the `print` method chooses to stick a comma in there?

Comment: Very slick idea.  Forcing lists into data frames is a little nonstandard though and is likely to lead to hard to understand code.  Notice that the output from `write.csv` is also a bit odd.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not improve the `write.csv` output; I believe it is because each element of the dataframe is a matrix as you both noted. Any ideas?:-)

Comment: @Avitus how about `data.frame( Number = 1:length(L) , Type = do.call( paste , L ) )`? Does that help with your output?

Comment: @RichieCotton actually it's one of the documented use cases of `I()` (but agreed it's not one that is well used)... *and ensures that matrices are inserted as single columns.*

Comment: @CarlWitthoft no I am not sure!

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon the .csv output is still strange; the element `df[2,2]` has now a complicated structure given by `[1] Eldar Tau
Levels: Eldar Tau Ork Nid`.

Comment: @Avitus ok `data.frame( Number = 1:length(L) , Type = do.call( paste , L ) , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )`! And do you want the screen output to look right or the csv output?

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon now the dataframe works fine: thank you very much! The write.csv does not however: is there some trick to use, like a special sep="..."?

Comment: @Avitus `data.frame( Number = 1:length(L) , Type = sapply( L , paste , collapse = " , " ) , stringsAsFactors = FALSE )`

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon I thank you very much and I apologize for this long thread, but the write.csv does not work properly. It does not recognize the 2 columns in the df, sticking all together. I removed the column Type and specified row.names=FALSE in write.csv. The output is good, now. I will work with that :-)

Comment: ...sorry, the column "Number", not the column "Type".

Answer (score 1):

You can change the shape of your data using:

```
data.frame(
  Number = seq_along(L),
  Type   = vapply(L, toString, character(1))
)
```

If you are using commas in your values (as in the `Type` column) you might prefer to save your files using tabs as the delimiter rather than commas.  (Call `read.delim` in place of `read.csv`.)  R will correctly quote values with commas, but other software may require some fiddling to read the file.

Comment: I swapped `sapply` for `vapply` because it works correctly when `L` has length zero.